# Force a page refresh when page visited from back button

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, refresh, page-refresh

How can I force a page refresh of page 1 when a user returns to it from page 2 by pressing the back button? Are there vbscript or javascript approaches or is it down to set the 'no cache' somehow?

Answer (score 6):

Set a cookie on page 2.

If the cookie is detected on page 1, reload the page.

Comment: Diodeus, that was my intended approach but I though there might be a better way...  Thanks for replying.

Comment: There are many examples of reading and setting cookies on this site already.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing something like this?

```
<script>
    if   (document.referrer == "http://www.page2.html") 
          window.location.reload(); 
    }
</script>
```

Just throw that at the top of your page 1 and this should work.

**Update**

I also found [a solution on the Webdeveloper.com forums](https://web.archive.org/web/20120327151715/http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=137518) as well.

Comment: Ascalonian, I tried this to occur on the body onload but it doesn't seem to recognised the referrer if it's been referred via the back button.  Any ideas?