# After clicking Browser back button, BeforePageLoad-Code not run

Tags: xpages

My problem is that after clicking the Browser back button the code in the BeforePagesLoad-Event not triggered. There is a function to get set an object in a manged bean.
I dry to set the cache control to no-store but that don't work. [the-order-of-events-in-xpages](http://linqed.eu/2011/11/23/the-order-of-events-in-xpages/)
Is there a way to trigger a event after clicking the browser back button?

Answer (score 0):

I am no x-pages expert, but it looks to be a server side technology, meaning that a server call must be made in order for the code to run.

The first thread is a solution for forcing a page reload via cookies, while the second involves javascript/jquery.  The second also may touch on some cache control of different browsers.

[Force a page refresh when page visited from back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215993/force-a-page-refresh-when-page-visited-from-back-button)

[Is there a cross-browser onload event when clicking the back button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158319/cross-browser-onload-event-and-the-back-button)