# How to make when user click back button, will be appear document expired

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3, kohana-auth

can i realize, when user in controller a... and then the user going into controller b...
When user click the back button, how to make Document expired..
but in both controller a and b ISN'T a form submit..
for information i using kohana framework and php 5.6..
kohana is fork framwork from codeigniter

## kohanaframework #php5.6 #php

when i tried put code like this in header stil not work

```
$cache_control = array(
            'max-age'          => 15,
            'must-revalidate' => True,
            'public'
        );
```

Comment: How's your Javascript or Jquery?  Basically you need something that will detect that this page isn't the most recent and hide it or refresh it.

Comment: i'm newbie about php...haha..and i doing nothing on js side..

Comment: Read this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215993/force-a-page-refresh-when-page-visited-from-back-button

Comment: oke..thanks @Forbs